# Removing inline image from paragraph

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, openxml

I'm having an XSLT problem and I'm completely stuck.

My case is as follows, I'm receiving a word document. Which I have to translate to our internal XML format. In this format images **have** to be separated from paragraphs.

I've tried numerous things like for each loops, templates, using helpercode, but I think my knowledge in XSLT is to limited to fix the issue.

In easy terms the Wordxml I receive is as follows

```
<w:document>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>sometext</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:drawing></w:drawing>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>anothertext</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:document>
```

I'm trying to create either of the following results.

Option1:

```
<w:document>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>sometext</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:drawing></w:drawing>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>anothertext</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:document>
```

Option2:

```
<w:document>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>sometext</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>anothertext</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:drawing></w:drawing>
</w:document>
```

Comment: Input XML and XML in option2 are not well-formed XMLs. Could you please confirm whether the appropriate closing tags are missed or not available intentionally.

Comment: corrected my not well-formed XML's

Comment: Just to confirm on the desired outputs as they have more than one document element. This again makes them not well-formed XMLs. Are you sure you want the same output as mentioned in the options?

Comment: These paragraph blocks are a small part of the entire document. they will be surrounded by an all-containing root node. clarified starting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:r/w:drawing]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(w:drawing)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:drawing"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm not sure if this will cover all possibilities, but it should output as per Option 2 with the sample given.

Comment: I could only reproduce this solution by also adding the identity template.

Comment: This isn't a complete stylesheet, it's a template that will effect the desired changes. I don't know what other processing is required, so I didn't assume that the identity template was suitable. I don't really consider it my job to write the OP's xslt for them, only to help them to do so.

Comment: Well, then just consider this a note.

Comment: thanks, for the baseline. Using this i could make additonal changes to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for *option 1*:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">               <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:p">                     <!-- remove outter w:p -->
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:r[w:drawing]">          <!-- move up w:drawing one level -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:r">                     <!-- encapsulate w:r in w:p and copy it -->
  <w:p>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </w:p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: while this answer is pretty clear and outputs my desired solution (option 1) i haven't used it, because the other answer given was more specific, thus could be applied with less side-effects than this solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your decision.